# Day and night averages SQlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a db with many years of ambient temperature, I need to make the average temperature from every month from 06:00 to 20:00 (day) and night. What I already made is

```
SELECT
    STRFTIME('%Y', fecha) AS year,
    STRFTIME('%m', fecha) AS month,

   AVG(T10_AVG) AS Temp_prom,
   FROM GER
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y', fecha), STRFTIME('%m', fecha)
```

But I have no idea how to include the day and night averages.

Comment: In the same query? What is the format of `fecha`?

Comment: Is the in the same query,  the format of fecha is yyyy-mm-dd and in other  column I have the hour register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get those averages in the same monthly output record, you cannot add another GROUP BY column.
You have to compute these values with separate subqueries:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', fecha) AS year,
       strftime('%m', fecha) AS month,
       (SELECT AVG(T10_AVG)
        FROM Ger AS g2
        WHERE g2.fecha GLOB strftime('%Y-%m*', Ger.fecha)
          AND (g2.hour >= '06' AND g2.hour < '20')
       ) AS avg_day,
       (SELECT AVG(T10_AVG)
        FROM Ger AS g2
        WHERE g2.fecha GLOB strftime('%Y-%m*', Ger.fecha)
          AND (g2.hour < '06' OR g2.hour >= '20')
       ) AS avg_night,
       AVG(T10_AVG) AS Temp_prom
FROM Ger
GROUP BY year, month
```